# What is the difference between JavaScript Frameworks like Vue, React and Angular and Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, vue.js

I've been using Bootstrap for a long time and have found it quite useful. Now I've came across tools like VueJS, ReactJS and AngularJS. Are they built to solve same problem Bootstrap is solving? If they aren't, what problem do they solve?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I request all of you that It takes time for people to learn how to ask questions. Instead of down voting the question, make an edit to it.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a **css/ui** library, in other words it provides you with styles for your web project. While `vue`, `react` and `angular` are **`js frameworks`** which are used to create **`SPA`** or **`single page application`**.

There is nothing stopping you from using bootstrap with any of the above. Since you are already familiar with bootstrap's classes and functionality all you will need to do is to give these classes to **DOM elements** to give your application a bootstrap look.